# How do I iterate over an array, use it in my view and remove each value so it calls an API Get request when array is empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @request = ClassName.search("kayak")
    @products = @request.paginate(params[:page], 30)
  end
end
```

I'm not storing anything in ActiveRecord.

My view iterates over @products which is an Array of OpenStructs.

My problem is everything displays correctly, but each request returns a capped # of products. I'm completely lost at this point on how and where I should call the new request & add the newly found products to @products so they can be used in my view with

```
<%= will_paginate @products %>
```

ie; Call request -> populate @products -> show @products in view & paginate them, -> upon all @products being displayed, call another request and populate @products while continuing to paginate them.

Comment: What you're looking for is "infinite scroll". You can refer here https://www.sitepoint.com/infinite-scrolling-rails-basics/

Comment: This isn't exactly what I need, sorry, but it is helpful in some regard.
Upon calling the request, let's say I can only receive 10 products at a time and want to paginate 5 at a time per page,  I will assign those to products, iterate through them in the view, and after the last product I need a way to call the request again & add them to products again, so that now the next 10 products will be paginated as "page 3, page 4"  and the next request will be "page 5, page 6" and so on.

Comment: No worries, however I still don't understand. Do you have an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Check it out here https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/wiki/How-To:-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery. The implementation is very simple with kaminari gem.

Comment: This would be very helpful, but i'm not using ActiveRecord as I have no database nor need to store any items.
All of my information is coming from an API.
The API sets a cap to how many products can be returned with each request before needing to send another request.
How would I accomplish this with/without infinite scroll?